# How to make Yen's Algorithm from Pyretic code into Python code in RYU controller?

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, sdn

I've got a reference from [here](http://csie.nqu.edu.tw/smallko/sdn/pyretic_yenksp.htm). How can I generate the Pyretic code into Python code for RYU controller, so I can use it to make Shortest Path Code?

This is a code that i try to make the Yen's Algorithm for RYU controller:

```
from ryu.base import app_manager

from ryu.controller import mac_to_port

from ryu.controller import ofp_event

from ryu.controller.handler import CONFIG_DISPATCHER, MAIN_DISPATCHER

from ryu.controller.handler import set_ev_cls

from ryu.ofproto import ofproto_v1_3

from ryu.lib.mac import haddr_to_bin

from ryu.lib.packet import packet

from ryu.lib.packet import ethernet

from ryu.lib.packet import ether_types

from ryu.lib import mac

 
from ryu.topology import event, switches
from ryu.topology.api import get_switch, get_link
from ryu.app.wsgi import ControllerBase
from collections import defaultdict

 

#switches

myswitches = []

 

#mymac[srcmac]->(switch, port)

mymac={}

 

#adjacency map [sw1][sw2]->port from sw1 to sw2

adjacency=defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:None))


datapath_list={}

def minimum_distance(distance, Q):
  #print "minimum_distance() is called", " distance=", distance, " Q=", Q

  min = float('Inf')

  node = 0

  for v in Q:

    if distance[v] < min:

      min = distance[v]

      node = v

  return node

 
#Awal codingan Algoritma
def path(previous, node_start, node_end):

  print "path is called, previous=", previous, " node_start=", node_start, " node_end=", node_end #ditambah

  r=[]

  p=node_end

  r.append(p)

  q=previous[p]

  while q is not None:

    if q == node_start:

      r.append(q)

      break

    p=q

    r.append(p)

    q=previous[p]

 

  r.reverse()

  if node_start==node_end:

    path=[node_start]

  else:

    path=r

  return r


def dijkstra(graph, node_start, node_end=None):

    distances = {}     

    previous = {}  

   

    for dpid in switches:

      distances[dpid] = float('Inf')

      previous[dpid] = None

 

    distances[node_start]=0

    Q=set(switches)

   

    while len(Q)>0:

      u = minimum_distance(distances, Q)

      Q.remove(u)  

  

      for p in switches:

        if graph[u][p]!=None:

          w = 1

          if distances[u] + w < distances[p]:

            distances[p] = distances[u] + w

            previous[p] = u

 

    if node_end:

        return {'cost': distances[node_end],

                'path': path(previous, node_start, node_end)}

    else:

        return (distances, previous)
 

def yen_ksp(src,dst,first_port,final_port,max_k=2):

  print "YenKSP is called"

  print "src=",src," dst=",dst, " first_port=", first_port, " final_port=", final_port, " max_k=", max_k 

  adjacency2=defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:None))

 

  distances, previous = dijkstra(adjacency,src)

  A = [{'cost': distances[dst],

          'path': path(previous, src, dst)}]

  B = []

  print "distances=", distances #dirubah

  print  "previous=", previous #dirubah

  print "A=", A #dirubah

 

  if not A[0]['path']: return A

 

  for k in range(1, max_k):

    adjacency2=copy.deepcopy(adjacency)

    print "k=", k, " adjacency2=", adjacency2 #dirubah

    for i in range(0, len(A[-1]['path']) - 1):

      node_spur = A[-1]['path'][i]

      path_root = A[-1]['path'][:i+1]

      #print "node_spur=", node_spur, " path_root=", path_root

 

      for path_k in A:

        curr_path = path_k['path']

        #print "curr_path=", curr_path, " i=", i

        if len(curr_path) > i and path_root == curr_path[:i+1]:

          adjacency2[curr_path[i]][curr_path[i+1]]=None

          #print "link[", curr_path[i],"][", curr_path[i+1], "] is removed"

           

      path_spur = dijkstra(adjacency2, node_spur, dst)

      #print "path_spur=", path_spur

 

      if path_spur['path']:

        path_total = path_root[:-1] + path_spur['path']

        #print "path_total=", path_total

        dist_total = distances[node_spur] + path_spur['cost']

        #print "dist_total=", path_total

        potential_k = {'cost': dist_total, 'path': path_total}

        #print "potential_k=", potential_k

 

        if not (potential_k in B):

          B.append(potential_k)

          #print "B=", B

 

    if len(B):

      B = sorted(B, key=itemgetter('cost'))

      #print "after sorting, B=", B

      A.append(B[0])

      B.pop(0)

      #print "after poping out the first element, B=", B, " A=", A

    else:

      break

 

  tmp=[]

  print "YenKSP->"

  for path_k in A:

     selected_path = path_k['path']

     print selected_path

     tmp.append(selected_path)

 

  ChosenPath=random.choice(tmp)

  print "Chosen Path=", ChosenPath

  #Now add the ports

  r = []

  in_port = first_port

  for s1,s2 in zip(ChosenPath[:-1],ChosenPath[1:]):

    out_port = adjacency[s1][s2]

    r.append((s1,in_port,out_port))

    in_port = adjacency[s2][s1]

  r.append((dst,in_port,final_port))

  #print r

  return r


def get_path (src,dst,first_port,final_port):

  print "Dijkstra's algorithm"

  print "src=",src," dst=",dst, " first_port=", first_port, " final_port=", final_port

  distance = {}

  previous = {}

 

  for dpid in switches:

    distance[dpid] = float('Inf')

    previous[dpid] = None

 

  distance[src]=0

  Q=set(switches)

   

  while len(Q)>0:

    u = minimum_distance(distance, Q)

    Q.remove(u)

   

    for p in switches:

      if adjacency[u][p]!=None:

        w = 1

        if distance[u] + w < distance[p]:

          distance[p] = distance[u] + w

          previous[p] = u

 

  r=[]

  p=dst

  r.append(p)

  q=previous[p]

  while q is not None:

    if q == src:

      r.append(q)

      break

    p=q

    r.append(p)

    q=previous[p]

 

  r.reverse()

  if src==dst:

    path=[src]

  else:

    path=r

 

  # Now add the ports

  r = []

  in_port = first_port

  for s1,s2 in zip(path[:-1],path[1:]):

    out_port = adjacency[s1][s2]

    r.append((s1,in_port,out_port))

    in_port = adjacency[s2][s1]

  r.append((dst,in_port,final_port))

  return r
#Akhir codingan algoritma
 

class ProjectController(app_manager.RyuApp):

    OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_3.OFP_VERSION]

 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(ProjectController, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.mac_to_port = {}

        self.topology_api_app = self

  

    # Handy function that lists all attributes in the given object

    def ls(self,obj):

        print("\n".join([x for x in dir(obj) if x[0] != "_"]))

 

    def add_flow(self, datapath, in_port, dst, actions):

        ofproto = datapath.ofproto

        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser      

        match = datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPMatch(

            in_port=in_port, eth_dst=dst)

        

        inst = [parser.OFPInstructionActions(ofproto.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS,

                                             actions)] 

 

        mod = datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPFlowMod(

            datapath=datapath, match=match, cookie=0,

            command=ofproto.OFPFC_ADD, idle_timeout=0, hard_timeout=0,

            priority=ofproto.OFP_DEFAULT_PRIORITY, instructions=inst)

        datapath.send_msg(mod)

 

    def install_path(self, p, ev, src_mac, dst_mac):

       print "install_path is called"

       #print "p=", p, " src_mac=", src_mac, " dst_mac=", dst_mac

       msg = ev.msg

       datapath = msg.datapath

       ofproto = datapath.ofproto

       parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

       for sw, in_port, out_port in p:

         print src_mac,"->", dst_mac, "via ", sw, " in_port=", in_port, " out_port=", out_port

         match=parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port, eth_src=src_mac, eth_dst=dst_mac)

         actions=[parser.OFPActionOutput(out_port)]

         datapath=datapath_list[sw]

         inst = [parser.OFPInstructionActions(ofproto.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS , actions)]

         mod = datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPFlowMod(

            datapath=datapath, match=match, idle_timeout=0, hard_timeout=0,

            priority=1, instructions=inst)

         datapath.send_msg(mod)

 

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPSwitchFeatures , CONFIG_DISPATCHER)

    def switch_features_handler(self , ev):

         print "switch_features_handler is called"

         datapath = ev.msg.datapath

         ofproto = datapath.ofproto

         parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

         match = parser.OFPMatch()

         actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER, ofproto.OFPCML_NO_BUFFER)]

         inst = [parser.OFPInstructionActions(ofproto.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS ,

actions)]

         mod = datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPFlowMod(

         datapath=datapath, match=match, cookie=0,

            command=ofproto.OFPFC_ADD, idle_timeout=0, hard_timeout=0,

            priority=0, instructions=inst)

         datapath.send_msg(mod)

 

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPacketIn, MAIN_DISPATCHER)

    def _packet_in_handler(self, ev):
        #print "packet_in event:", ev.msg.datapath.id, " in_port:", ev.msg.match['in_port']

        msg = ev.msg

        datapath = msg.datapath

        ofproto = datapath.ofproto

        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

        in_port = msg.match['in_port']

 

        pkt = packet.Packet(msg.data)

        eth = pkt.get_protocol(ethernet.ethernet)

        #print "eth.ethertype=", eth.ethertype

 

        #avodi broadcast from LLDP

        if eth.ethertype==35020:

          return

 

        dst = eth.dst

        src = eth.src

        dpid = datapath.id
        #print "src=", src, " dst=", dst, " type=", hex(eth.ethertype)
        #print "adjacency=", adjacency

        self.mac_to_port.setdefault(dpid, {})

 

        if src not in mymac.keys():

            mymac[src]=( dpid,  in_port)

            #print "mymac=", mymac

 

        if dst in mymac.keys():

            p = get_path(mymac[src][0], mymac[dst][0], mymac[src][1], mymac[dst][1])

            print "Path=", p

            self.install_path(p, ev, src, dst)

            out_port = p[0][2]

        else:

            out_port = ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD

       

        actions = [parser.OFPActionOutput(out_port)]

 

        # install a flow to avoid packet_in next time

        if out_port != ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD:

            match = parser.OFPMatch(in_port=in_port, eth_src=src, eth_dst=dst)

       

        data=None

        if msg.buffer_id==ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER:

           data=msg.data

  
        if out_port == ofproto.OFPP_FLOOD:
           #print "FLOOD"
           while len(actions) > 0 : actions.pop()
           for i in range(1,23):
              actions.append(parser.OFPActionOutput(i))
           #print "actions=", actions
           out = parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath, buffer_id=msg.buffer_id,
                                  in_port=in_port, actions=actions, data=data)
           datapath.send_msg(out)   
 
        else:      
          #print "unicast"
          out = parser.OFPPacketOut(

              datapath=datapath, buffer_id=msg.buffer_id, in_port=in_port,

              actions=actions, data=data)

          datapath.send_msg(out)

    
    events = [event.EventSwitchEnter, 
          event.EventSwitchLeave, event.EventPortAdd,
          event.EventPortDelete, event.EventPortModify,
          event.EventLinkAdd, event.EventLinkDelete]
    #@set_ev_cls(event.EventSwitchEnter)
    @set_ev_cls(events)
    def get_topology_data(self, ev):
        print "get_topology_data() is called"

        global myswitches, adjacency, datapath_list

        switch_list = get_switch(self.topology_api_app, None) 
         
        myswitches=[switch.dp.id for switch in switch_list]
   
        for switch in switch_list:
          datapath_list[switch.dp.id]=switch.dp

        print "datapath_list=", datapath_list

        print "myswitches=", myswitches

        links_list = get_link(self.topology_api_app, None)
        #print "links_list=", links_list 
        mylinks=[(link.src.dpid,link.dst.dpid,link.src.port_no,link.dst.port_no) for link in links_list]

        for s1,s2,port1,port2 in mylinks:
          #print "type(s1)=", type(s1), " type(port1)=", type(port1)
          adjacency[s1][s2]=port1

          adjacency[s2][s1]=port2

          print s1,":", port1, "<--->",s2,":",port2
```

Hope you guys can give some advice for me or some examples code yen's algorithm that is use in RYU controller, so I can understand it more, thankyou and stay healthy :))

Comment: Welcome to SO, sharing such a huge chunk of code tends to keep the many in the community from reading through completely and help. Can you make it shorter? Also there seems the be a lot of newlines which means we have to scroll a lot to understand your implementation.

Comment: In short, I'm looking for the yen algorithm source code or any suggest code that can be used on the Ryu controller using yen's algorithm.

my brain will explode soon hahaha